# iPhone Mobile Safari File System Access

Tags: iphone, safari, filesystems, mobile-safari

Is it possible to write to a file in a native iPhone application and have a Safari browser read from that file after having the browser opened from the native app?

Alternatively (and this would be great!), would it be possible to launch a mobile Safari webapp from a native iPhone app, and have that application access the OS 3.0 External Accessory Framework?  My assumption is no...

Basically, I have a functioning iPhone app that wraps a simple mobile Safari webapp, but I'd like to utilize the external accessory framework once I have launched the Safari webapp from the iPhone app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different interpretations. If you want to *launch* MobileSafari from your app, then the answers will be **no** since MobileSafari and your app are isolated by sandboxes. But you may include the detail in the URL like

- `http://example.com?info=SXMgaXQgcG9zc2libGUgdG8gd3JpdGUgdG8gYSBma…`

But you can embed a UIWebView in your app, then the answers will be **yes** (to the UIWebView), since you may communicate with the web view with any ObjC code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the phonegap framework : it provide a project template and libraries to access native function in javascript (like writing/reading a file).

Consider also the localstorage and the SQLLite DB...